# Arquivos PHP não atualizam as alterações de CSS e Javascript

Tags: php, html, css, cache, wamp

Isso já havia acontecido comigo anteriormente, mas eu resolvia dando um CTRL + F5. Agora NADA adianta. Já reiniciei o wamp várias vezes, reiniciei inclusive o computador e nada. O curioso é que só acontece nas página php. As páginas html estão atualizando normalmente. Sei que é um problema de cache, mas não sei o que fazer para resolver.

```
    <html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="../css/pequeno.css" media="screen and (min-width: 0px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../css/medio.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1000px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../css/estilo.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1500px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Página principal</title>
  </head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61123/discussion-on-question-by-sabrina-t-arquivos-php-nao-atualizam-as-alteracoes-de)

Answer (score 0):

Então, coloque um numero aleatorio ao final de cada arquivo, dessa forma o navegador não o encontrará no cache e irá buscá-lo no servidor.

```
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="../css/pequeno.css?<?php echo rand(1, 1000);?>" media="screen and (min-width: 0px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../css/medio.css?<?php echo rand(1, 1000);?>" media="screen and (min-width: 1000px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../css/estilo.css?<?php echo rand(1, 1000);?>" media="screen and (min-width: 1500px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Página principal</title>
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js?<?php echo rand(1, 1000);?>"></script>
```

Comment: Oi, Leo. Fiz exatamente como você postou e não adiantou. Reiniciei novamente o servidor e nada também. É possível que o problema esteja no servidor? O estranho é que até ontem a noite estava conseguindo fazer as alterações normalmente e do nada parou.